# Upgrade an Ubuntu 8.04 installation with VMware Server 1.0.8 and lots of guest OSes to Something Else

Tags: ubuntu, virtualization, vmware-server, ubuntu-10.04

I have an Ubuntu 8.04 (Hardy Heron) host machine which is running a whole slew of virtual machines in VMWare Server 1.0.8.  Among other guest OSes, there is every release version of Ubuntu since 6.06, OpenSolaris 2009.06, and Windows XP.  Right now I access these VMs from a variety of client OSes as well; Linux and Windows via the VMWare server console, and MacOS via X-forwarding the host machine's server console.

I'd like to upgrade the host to Ubuntu 10.04 (Lucid Lynx), but from what I can tell, getting VMWare Server 1.x to work on a more recent version of Linux is a real pain.  While VMware Server 2.x is a bit easier, it's still not packaged as Debian packages, so installing security updates is a big chore.  As long as I'm upgrading anyway, I'd like to move to a virtualization solution that will allow me to automate applying updates.

The options that I'm aware of right now are [KVM](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Main_Page) (managed via [virt-manager](http://virt-manager.et.redhat.com/)) and [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) (as managed by its own tools *or* via [its own libvirt bindings](http://libvirt.org/drvvbox.html)), but I'm open to other suggestions.

For each option, I'd like to know

- how do I convert my guest images to the new format?
- am I going to have to re-activate my Windows guests (alternatively, "If the virtual hardware is different by default, can I avoid re-activation by changing some virtualization configuration to provide me with more similar virtual hardware")
- what are the management options like for each client OS (mac, linux, windows)?

Thanks.

Comment: Glyph - I'm just curious about the motivation to update the host OS - you're opening the door to a bunch of pain (risk).

Comment: The question about risk is a valid one, so here's why I'd like to upgrade:

Every time I install security updates right now, it breaks the VMWare installation and I need to reconfigure it and re-apply a couple of hand tweaks to work around bugs in this version of VMWare Server.  Upgrading to 2.0 on this particular version of ubuntu is supposedly unpleasant.  I also want to make use of new filesystems and new management tools in Lucid.  This is a server that gets put to a lot of different uses, and there are just newer versions of software packaged in Lucid that I'd rather be using.

Comment: Does your hardware support ESXi?  Have you considered migrating to that?

Comment: I don't know if my hardware supports ESXi; I suspect not.  However, my understanding is that ESXi is just a hypervisor, and the host machine here has several responsibilities beyond just running the VMs, so I'd like to just dump VMWare entirely for this host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as conversion goes, I would use [qemu-img](http://linux.die.net/man/1/qemu-img), a part of the [QEMU](http://www.qemu.org) emulator. The tool `qemu-img` appears to convert to and from most formats, including VirtualBox, VMware, QEMU, raw, and others. Specific details can be found via Google.

I would say that the chances are you'll have to re-validate all your Windows installations; even if the hardware was identical the IDs that the CPUs are tagged with are almost certainly going to be different.

I don't know what you mean by *management options* in particular. If you are talking about managing virtual machines (whether from inside the host like *VMware Tools* or from outside the host like *vSphere*) there are tools for some operating systems from the virtual machine emulator. As for something like *vSphere* there are open source versions of this but they would have to work with the particular VM emulator you went with.

The [virt-manager](http://virt-manager.org/index.html) from Red Hat that you mentioned not only manages KVM hosts, but also QEMU and Xen hosts as well. I know there are other open source products like it, but I can't find them right now.

Comment: Thanks.  I was kinda leaning towards something KVM-based, but it's nice to hear someone else confirm my suspicions about the migration process :).